# Jersey controlling serverside logging

Tags: logging, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey to develop my restful services.
I have exposed a /health service endpoint in our app, so that the load balancer will hit this url periodically(every sec) to check the health of our application.

As Jersey will print all the server requests received, it is printing all the hits by the load balancer to the /health service. 
As these requests were too many, these log statements were becoming too many and our log files were n't looking readable. It is taking more time to find out actual log statements.

Is there anyway to control the log statements so that I can avoid logging the hits by load balancer to the health url endpoint?

Comment: Which log is it ? Is this the application server / container log or a one which you are handling ?

Comment: yes. It is the container log

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a log which is maintained by your servlet container, you'll have to check your container's documentation about access log. For example, if you are using Tomcat as your servlet container, you can use the `condition*` variable, to filter out entries from your access log ([Tomcat's Access Log Attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes).

Another option is to implement a custom Jersey filter which logs all requested endpoints except `/health`. You can find a stub of it here: [Logging Filter](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/jaxrs/examples/filter/logging/LoggingFilter.java)

Good luck!